# Where is the Spark UI on Google Dataproc?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

What port should I use to access the Spark UI on Google Dataproc?

I tried port 4040 and 7077 as well as a bunch of other ports I found using `netstat -pln`

Firewall is properly configured.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Dataproc runs Spark on top of YARN, so you won't find the typical "Spark standalone" ports; instead, when running a Spark job, you can visit port `8088` which will show you the YARN ResourceManager's main page. Any running Spark jobs will be accessible through the `Application Master` link on that page. The Spark Application Master's page looks the same as the familiar Spark-standalone landing page that you would normally find on port 8080 for default Spark setups.

Since workers check in over the internal network, YARN's links will be using cluster-internal hostnames (the hostnames should include your Dataproc cluster name as a prefix), but this means if you're accessing from the outside network, the links may not work at first; you have to replace the hostname with the external IP address if you're using the firewall-based approach.

An easier experience will be to use the SOCKS proxy approach as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/cluster-web-interfaces

In that case, simply using `gcloud compute ssh` to run a lightweight local socks proxy and then opening a browser pointed at that will let you click all the YARN links as normal.

Comment: Spark UI for finished jobs will also be available under the "History" link on the job entry.

Comment: On another note, like hortonworks and cloudera both provide an UI interface, does dataproc has any ?

Comment: Replacing the hostname with private IP doesn't work for some reason....

Answer (score 3):

When [following the instructions in Dennis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193122/where-is-the-spark-ui-on-google-dataproc/33193325#33193325), I found that I could not connect to ports 8080 or 8088 for dataproc image v1.0.

The open ports on the master node suggested to use 18080, which I did following [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/cluster-web-interfaces) for port 18080 and voilá: Access to webui.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had public addresses in my DataProc cluster I created a Firewall rule in Cloud Console from my corporate subnet to DataProc instances ports **8088** (YARN RM) and **8042** (NM Webapp address).

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the Spark UI you can follow these steps:

1. First, don't forget to mark the `Enable component gateway` option in the `Components` section of the `Set up cluster` tab while creating the Dataproc cluster.
2. After the cluster is running, go to the [Dataproc page](https://console.cloud.google.com/dataproc) in the GCP Console: Dataproc -> Clusters
3. Find the cluster in the list and click on its link under the Name column for accessing the [Cluster Details](https://console.cloud.google.com/dataproc/clusters/put-cluster-name-here?region=put-region-here&project=put-project-id-here) page.
4. In the Cluster Details page click on the [Web Interfaces](https://console.cloud.google.com/dataproc/clusters/put-cluster-name-here/interfaces?region=put-region-here&project=put-project-id-here) tab.
5. In the `Web Interfaces` tab click on the [YARN ResourceManager](https://put-generated-interface-id-here.dataproc.googleusercontent.com/yarn/) link.
6. The browser will open a new page for the `YARN ResourceManager` showing all available applications.
7. Find the application with the type `SPARK` and the state `RUNNING` in the list/table on the `YARN ResourceManager` page.
8. Scroll right and click on the link [ApplicationMaster](https://put-generated-interface-id-here.dataproc.googleusercontent.com/gateway/default/yarn/proxy/put-application_id_num/) in the `Tracking UI` column.
9. After this, you'll be forwarded to the Spark UI page.